# Loop variable as parameter in asynchronous function call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, async.js

I have an object with the following form.

```
sortedFilters:
  {
    task:{...},
    appointment:{...},
    email:{...}
  }
```

Now i want to use a `for-in` loop, to build my tasks array for `async.parallel`, which contains the functions to be executed asynchronously:

```
var tasks = [];
for (var entity in sortedFilters) {
  tasks.push(function(callback) {
    var entityResult = fetchRecordsForEntity(entity, businessUnits, sortedFilters);
    var formattedEntityResults = formatResults(entity, entityResult);  
    callback(null, formattedEntityResults);
  });
}
```

The problem is, that at the moment the functions are called, `entity` points at the last value of the loop (in this case it would be `email`).

How can i nail the exact value at the moment the function is added to the array?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more which functions you are talking about in the end, and in how far `sortedFilters` is enumerable by a `for…in` loop? Especially I don't get the connection between your sample and the `async.parallel` call. Where and how does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **create a scope** for the variable:

```
var tasks = [];
for (var en in sortedFilters) {
  (function(entity) {
     tasks.push(function(callback) {
        var entityResult = fetchRecordsForEntity(entity, businessUnits, sortedFilters);
        var formattedEntityResults = formatResults(entity, entityResult);  
        callback(null, formattedEntityResults);
     });
  })(en);
}
```